# Is it possible to remove all events attached to an element and its children

Tags: jquery

I need to be able to remove events attached to an element and all its children even when I don't know what these events are. All the events are attached using jquery.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For jQuery 1.8 and later, use

```
$(element).find("*").addBack().off();
```

`addBack()` adds the original list of elements from `$(element)` back to the internal collection of elements held by the jQuery object (those returned by `find("*")`).  `off()` removes all attached event handlers, including those using delegation.

If you just want children and not all descendants, use

```
$(element).children().addBack().off();
```

See the documentation:

- [addBack()](http://api.jquery.com/addback/)
- [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

---

For jQuery 1.7 and lower, use `andSelf()` instead of `addBack()`.  For jQuery 1.6 and lower, use `unbind()` and `die()` instead of `off()`.  For example:

```
$(element).children().andSelf().unbind().die();
```

Comment: thanks, will this unbind delegate() events, or do I need to unbind them with undelegate()

Comment: @SystemicPlural: no, it won't unbind those events.  You can use `undelegate()` or `die()` just by chaining it on the end above.

Answer (score 2):

andSelf() function is deprecated.

Use add() function:

```
$(element).add("*").off();
```

Comment: I think you could only replace `addSelf()` for `addBack()`

Comment: andSelf() is deprecated, $(element).children().addBack() is equivalent to $(element).add("*")

Comment: They're not equivalent. The latter (your answer) selects every element in the DOM. To correct this you would need to give context to the "*" selector i.e. `$( element ).add( "*", element ).off();`

Answer (score 0):

Use the .unbind() method on the element.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but it is worth mentioning.

I had used a third party plugin without a destroy method. I found this solution but it didn't work at the beginning until I started digging deeper into the documentation.

Note that if the plugin are creating a `$(document).on(event, handler)` listener on your object, you have to remove the action by writing `$(document).off(event, 'element, element *')`. Simply writing `$(element).find("*").addBack().off();` won't work if the main listener is the `document`.